# 100% GPU Usage but < 40W Power Draw

Tags: nvidia, blender

My GPU utilization, when rendering scenes in Blender, is completely maxed:

```
Mon Dec 12 20:33:51 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.60.11    Driver Version: 525.60.11    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P0    36W /  N/A |   2153MiB /  6144MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3232      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                201MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3403      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              132MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4006    C+G   ...r-3.4.0-linux-x64/blender     1700MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4890      G   ...040712106758151386,131072      102MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8481      G   /usr/bin/gjs                        9MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, my power draw is nowhere near maxed:

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                                 : Mon Dec 12 20:34:32 2022
Driver Version                            : 525.60.11
CUDA Version                              : 12.0

Attached GPUs                             : 1
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Power Readings
        Power Management                  : N/A
        Power Draw                        : 35.25 W
        Power Limit                       : N/A
        Default Power Limit               : N/A
        Enforced Power Limit              : N/A
        Min Power Limit                   : N/A
        Max Power Limit                   : N/A
```

This is when plugged in to the stock 300W charger, power draw drops to 20W when unplugged. Windows claims that the maximum graphics power is 130W, which is corroborated by online sources. However, the same Blender Render in classroom also draws between 35-37W, far below the rated power draw for my GPU.

I have an NVIDIA RTX 3060 Mobile paired with a Ryzen 5800H in my Lenovo Legion 5. I am running PopOS 22.04 LTS, using the latest NVIDIA driver (525), and the latest kernel (6.07-76). The power draw is the same, regardless of whether I use switchable or discrete graphics. This is with the High Performance battery setting, the Performance Lenovo power setting, and "Prefer Maximum Performance" in the X Server settings.

Comment: Please ask here instead https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, **it is specific to Lenovo Legion laptops**. If the USB-PD is used to charge the laptop, there is a chance of it getting stuck in low-power mode, despite changing to the barrel plug.

This is solved by removing power, going to the BIOS and toggling off the battery for service, letting the computer fully shut off, then finally plugging in power again (not USB-PD).